# construct object from parent class

Tags: java

A extends B, may i reference B suboject in A's constructor?

```
public A(B b)
{
  /*(B)this = b*/
}
```

If not, how do i construct an A object with a B object?, i mean other that using Cloneable to create some other instance or solutions out of the JLS (dozer, beanutils, etc.). In a nutshell, how would the A constructor look like to make this code to run?

```
B b = new B("hi");
A a = new A(b);
assertequals(a.getSalute(), "hi");//ok so far

a.setSalute("hola");
assertequals(b.getSalute(), "hola");//A maintains a reference to B

f(a);//prints hola
f(b);//prints hola as well
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you mean casting from `A` to `B`,  won't work because you cannot cast up the hierachy.

Comment: I'm gonna guess here... "how do i construct an A object with a B object", you want to create a new 'dog' with a given 'animal' object? (Dog extends Animal) But, how would _this_ 'dog' become _that_ 'animal'?

Comment: You're both right, i'm not fluent in the java language i thought the java language would allow the B 'suboject' in an A object refer to some other B object the way other languages do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying some kind of decorator pattern. I'm not the biggest fan of "program to an interface" because I think it's good advice that's over-used, but I think this is a good situation for it.

```
interface Wrapable { // replace Wrapable with something more appropriate
   // common methods here?
}

class B implements Wrapable {

}

class A implements Wrappable {
    Wrappable whatThisWraps;

    A(Wrappable w) { whatThisWraps = w; }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this is a solution in some situations but has drawbacks: A is never a B, in A methods you'd have to cast whatThisWraps down to B to refer to any B's field members.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Java does not disallow forward references to concrete classes the way C++ does.

You do have to be aware though of static class initializers.

From [DCL12-J. Prevent class initialization cycles](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/DCL12-J.+Prevent+class+initialization+cycles):

> According to §12.4, "Initialization of Classes and Interfaces" of the Java Language Specification [JLS 2005]
>
> > Initialization of a class consists of executing its `static` initializers and the initializers for `static` fields (class variables) declared in the class.
>
> In other words, the presence of a `static` field triggers the initialization of a class. However, a static field could depend on the initialization of a class, possibly creating an initialization cycle. The Java Language Specification also states in §8.3.2.1, "Initializers for Class Variables" [JLS 2005]
>
> > ...at run time, `static` variables that are `final` and that are initialized with compile-time constant values are initialized first.
>
> This statement can be misleading because it is inapplicable to instances that use values of `static final` fields that are initialized at a later stage. Declaring a field to be `static final` is insufficient to guarantee that it is fully initialized before being read.

Answer (score 0):

So long as your constructors are appropriately constructed, you can reference B in A's constructor as you described.

If A extends B, any A Object can be considered an B Object, but the reverse is not true.

To better answer your original question, creating a B from a A should be straightforward - change the A in the constructor to an B (since any A is also a B), call the appropriate getter methods and assign their values to the instance variables held by A. This type of constructor `public B(B b)...` is a copy-constructor. If you decide to keep A in the constructor, then just apply the call/copy/assign logic mentioned by calling all methods inherited by A from B.

Comment: Yes, but how do i do make the B suboject refer to the b object passed in the constructor? After all any A object is also a B object.

Comment: Updated the answer to provide more clarity on creating a copy of an A Object from a B Object. I'm still not totally certain what your first question in your comment is asking.

Comment: Yes, but it's the part of the getter/setter in the copy-constructor what i want to skip. After all i want 'b' and the B subject in some A object refer to the same object.

Comment: It sounds like you want to do this `new A();` where `public A() {super();}` and some initialization will take place in `public B(){...}` correct?